# Java. BufferedInputStream working with images

Tags: java, image, bufferedinputstream

I'm trying to write server and client sides on java.
So, client side sends request like GET / HTTP/1.0, server side responses(if file exists) like HTTP/1.0 200 OK, put in header content-type and content length and writes to the BufferedOuputStream the stream from FileInputStream.
Server side:

```
String endLine = "\r\n";
    File f = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fstream;
    fstream = new FileInputStream(f);
    response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" + endLine;
    header = "Content-type: "+ contentType + endLine + "Content-length: " + f.length() + endLine + endLine;
bout.write(response.getBytes());
            bout.write(header.getBytes());
            int lol;
        while((lol = fstream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bout.write(buffer,0,lol);
        }
            System.out.println("Message sent");
            bout.flush();
            socket.close();
```

Client side:

```
byte[] res = new byte[bufferSize];
            int got;
            int i=0;
            int temp = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while((got = bis.read(res))!=-1){
                for(j=0;j<res.length;j++){
                    //dividing from header
                    if(res[j]=='\n'&&res[j-1]=='\r'&&res[j-2]=='\n'&&res[j-3]=='\r'){
                        temp = j+1;
                    }
                }
                fout.write(res,temp,got-temp);
                i++;

            }
```

So, with .html files it works fine, but with images...
[image: Server side image]

[image: What do I have on client side]

Found the solution. The error was on offsets:

```
fout.write(res,temp,got-temp);
```

This line adds the offsets on every iteration. I need only on first:

```
if(i==0){
                fout.write(res,temp,got-temp);
            }else{
                fout.write(res,0,got);
            }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `HttpURLConnection` in the client?

Answer (score 0):

You should not parse the contents checking for new lines etc when transferring binary data, your pictures also contains these \n r characters

Comment: Oooh sorry, I've found the solution.